# How to get working react select in material UI?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I am using React Select material UI and the dropdown select is not working. The popup is not opening up.

I want to show react select in the modal dialog box.

```
import MenuItem from "@mui/material/MenuItem";
import FormControl from "@mui/material/FormControl";
import Select, { SelectChangeEvent } from "@mui/material/Select";

const [age, setAge] = React.useState("");
const handleChange1 = (event: SelectChangeEvent) => {
  setAge(event.target.value);
};
<FormControl sx={{ m: 1, minWidth: 80 }}>
  {/* <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-autowidth-label">Age</InputLabel> */}
  <Select
    value={age}
    onChange={handleChange1}
    autoWidth
    // label="Age"
  >
    <MenuItem value="">
      <em>None</em>
    </MenuItem>
    <MenuItem value={10}>Twenty</MenuItem>
    <MenuItem value={21}>Twenty one</MenuItem>
    <MenuItem value={22}>Twenty one and a half</MenuItem>
  </Select>
</FormControl>;
```

I'm also attaching the screenshot of the select dropdown. This is what I'm getting now.

[image]

I don't know why I'm getting that outline background even if I haven't applied that anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need SelectChangeEven inside (event: SelectChangeEvent) so I remove it and then the dropdown select will working fine.

[image]

You can try my code like below:

```js
const handleChange1 = (event) => {
  setAge(event.target.value);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not using **alias name** while setting **age**
Use alias name as shown in below code

```
const handleChange1 = (event: SelectChangeEvent) => {
  setAge(SelectChangeEvent.target.value);
};
```